# Turning a string into a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Having had a python class behind me, I was presented with this question in the next class and I seem to be having a mental block on how to even get started.

"Write a python program that asks the user for a string,  then create the following dictionary: The values are the letters in the string, with the corresponding key being the place in the string. For example if the user entered the string “ABC123” then the dictionary would be: D = {‘A’:0, ‘B’:1, ‘C’:2, ‘1’:3, ‘2’:4, ‘3’:5}

I started with asking for the user input with something simple like

```
s = input('Enter string: ')
```

however, I do not know how to proceed to the next step. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Not to be rude, but, as volunteers, our help is not predicated by your time crunch. Please review [ask] and make an attempt. We're not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: What's the expected output if the input is `'AA'`?

Comment: Expect output would be d = { 'A':0, 'A':1}

Also, sorry about how I worded my question. Did not mean to make it seem that way it did. I have edited it now.

Comment: Python dictionaries cannot have the same key map to two separate values. ``{'A': 0, 'A': 1}['A']`` will either return ``1`` or ``0`` but not both.

Comment: My teacher for this misrepresented what he was asking for in the instructions, which is why this seemed so off and partially why I was so confused. Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [55]: s = input("Enter a string: ")
Enter a string: ABC123

In [56]: d = {char:i for i,char in enumerate(s)}

In [57]: d
Out[57]: {'C': 2, '1': 3, '2': 4, '3': 5, 'B': 1, 'A': 0}
```

Note however, that if there are repeated characters in the user's input, `d` will have the index of the last occurrence of each character:

```
In [62]: s = input("Enter a string: ")
Enter a string: ABC123A

In [63]: d = {char:i for i,char in enumerate(s)}

In [64]: d
Out[64]: {'C': 2, '1': 3, '2': 4, '3': 5, 'B': 1, 'A': 6}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I think it needs to show all instances of every letter. so if AAA121 was entered, it would show:

    d = { 'A':0, 'A':1, 'A':2, '1':3, '2':4, '1':5}

Any ideas? Also thanks for the input, never knew about enumerate.

Comment: That is not how dictionaries work, which means that you are using the wrong data structure for this task. You might be able to use a dictionary who's keys are characters, and who's values are lists of positions where that character is found in the string. But that still wouldn't replicate the example in your comment

Answer (score 0):

this?

```
def dict():
    user_input = input("Please enter a string")
    dictionary = {}
    for i, j in enumerate(user_input):
        dictionary[j] = i
    print(dictionary)
dict("ABC123")
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need this output: D = {‘A’:0, ‘B’:1, ‘C’:2, ‘1’:3, ‘2’:4, ‘3’:5} and not D = {0:'A', 1:'B', 2:'C'...}? You can flip the key:values, but they will be unordered then (e.g. you would get something like: D = {‘B’:1, ‘3’:5, ‘A’:0, ‘C’:2, ‘1’:3, ‘2’:4 } or any other random combination).

It sounds like you are getting started with learning python. Welcome to a beautiful programming language. People are very helpful here, but you need to show some effort and initiative. This is not a place to get quick fix solutions. People may provide them to you, but you'll never learn.

I assume this was a HW related question? Unless I'm mistaken (someone please feel free to correct me), the output you are seeking is difficult, if not impossible to create (e.g in that specific order you want). I encourage you to read about python [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views).

Try and run this:

```
#user = input("Give me a string:")

#Just for demo purpose, lets 
#stick with your orig example 

user = "ABC123"

ls =[]  #create empty list
d = {}  #create empty dictionary 

#Try to figure out and understand 
#what the below code does 
#what is a list, tuple, dict?
#what are key:values?

for l in enumerate(user):
    ls.append(l)

    for k,v in ls:
        d[k] = v

print('first code output')
print(ls)
print(d)

#What/how does enumerate work? 
#the below will generate a 
#ordered dict by key 


for k,v in enumerate(user):
    d[k] = v

print('2nd code output')
print(d)


#you want to flip your key:value 
#output, bases on origibal question 
#notice what happens
#run this a few times 

print('3rd code output')

print(dict(zip(d.values(), d.keys())))


#You can get the order you want, 
#but as a list[(tuple)], not as
#a dict at least in the output
#from your orig question  

print(list(zip(d.values(), d.keys())))
```

Unless Im wrong, and someone more experienced can chime in, you cant get the "ordered" output in the format you want for your dictionary.

I'm on a mobile device, so anyone please feel free to correct things.